# I'm looking for a name of navbar example and what tools I need to make it like that

Tags: navbar

can anyone help me with the name of these types of navbars where navbar is fixed and NOT at the top, but as soon as you start to scroll it's fixed at the top.

Example : http://www.hcl.hr/

---

I want to know type name so I can look up on some tutorials and demonstrations. I hope there is some kind of name for it. I was trying something like "collapsing navbar" but all it gives me are bootstrap examples that dont look like that...

Also, if you know some tutorials/codes for it or know what tools i need to make it like that, i will be thankful. I have basic knowledge in html, css and js.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check this:

http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/

This is the demo:
http://www.dwuser.com/education/content/creating-a-floating-navigation-menu/demo/complete.html

Comment: Thanks, I believe that's it. Anyways, i have to test it for me now. Later.

Comment: Hey, i made it to work perfectly, but i didn't use that example. I tried it tho and it served purpose but it was shaky a lil bit when i scrolled. I found one similar on codepan searching for "sticky navbar". It works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I used [this](https://www.webpagefx.com/blog/web-design/fixed-navigation-bar/) tutorial to help make mine. For future reference, it's usually called a sticky bar, or something of the sort. W3Schools calls it a '[fixed menu](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_fixed_menu.asp)'.

Comment: I already have that type of navbar on my page actually. I want it to be fixed, but i also want to have some sort of header infront of it that will disappear while scrolling and when it disappears, the nav bar goes to top and it stays fixed.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the name "sticky navbar". I found one perfect example on codepan and it works for me too.